# Ant package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, junit, ant

For the first time I use Ant and the task was set that the project would create jar files, run tests, run jar files. Everything is successfully obtained except for tests for reasons that are not clear to me, by using this resource ["Getting started – Ant"](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started-%E2%80%93-Ant) I tried to download the test but it was not successful because for some reason the junit library is not visible. Here are my mistakes:

```
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Eclipse project\CalcSimple\build\main
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Eclipse project\CalcSimple\build\main
[javac] D:\Eclipse project\CalcSimple\src\testing\CalcAPITest.java:4: error: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import org.junit.Test;
```

[image]

The test itself workers there counting a primitive calculator.
Could not help finding the error and suggesting how to fix it?
Project Structure:
[image]

My code:

```
<project name="CalcAnt" basedir="." default="main">


    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main.build.dir" value="build/main"/>
    <property name="main.src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="test.build.dir" value="build/test"/>
    <property name="test.src.dir" value="src/testing"/>
    <property name="main-class"  value="CalcSimples.CalcSimple"/>

    <!--PATH LIB-->
    <path id="classpath.test">
        <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${main.build.dir}"/>
    </path>

        <!--CLEAN-->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

        <!--COMPILE-->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${main.build.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${main.src.dir}" destdir="${main.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

        <!--TEST-COMPILE-->
    <target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${test.build.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!--TEST-->
    <target name="test" depends="test-compile">
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath.test"/>
                <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" >
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <!--CREATE JAR-->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${main.build.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!--RUN JAR-->
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

    <!--CLEAN-BUILD-->
    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <!--MAIN-->
    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test lives below `src` and your "compile" target tries to compile it, which fails as the `javac` task doesn't know about junit.jar.

You need to move your tests out of the `src` directory or explicitly exclude the test from getting compiled by the "compile" target. If you want to keep `testing` as a subdirectory of `src` change the `javac` in "compile" to

```
<javac srcdir="${main.src.dir}" destdir="${main.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
    <exclude name="testing/**"/>
</javac>
```

Keeping main and test sources in separate source trees is considered best practice, though. Usually you'd create something like `src/main`, move the `CalcSimples` directory there and then set `main.src.dir` to `src/main`.